# TextBoxFor com espaços em branco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um TextBoxFor que lista o registro de um campo da tabela.
Ao exibir na view, o textbox lança espaços em branco após a exibição do conteudo do registro. Percebi que esses espaços são para completar o StringLegth definido no model para tamanho máximo de caracteres permitidos para o textBoxFor

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
[Display(Name = "Responsável")]
[StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Informe no máximo 80 caracteres")]
public string Responsavel { get; set; }
```

Na View eu coloco o TextBoxFor

```
@f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(p => p.Responsavel).WidthMd(6).Placeholder("Professor responsável pelo projeto.")
```

E o campo é listado da seguinte forma:

"João da Silva 'vários espaços em branco'" (sem as aspas, coloquei as aspas para mostrar que está sendo aplicado um espaço em branco).

Tenho outros formulários que fiz do mesmo jeito e isso não acontece, por que raios esse espaço em branco está incluindo?
Antes que alguem pergunte, o registro no BD não tem espaços.

Comment: Aparentemente vc está utilzando algumas extensões no helper `Html`. Sem saber o que elas fazem fica difícil ajudar. Pode postar o conteúdo delas?

Comment: No BD o campo é Char ou Varchar?

Answer (score 1):

**Descobri o problema**:

O campo no Sql Server estava como `nchar`, sendo que o correto é `nvarchar`.
Quem estava populando os valores com espaços era o banco.

Comment: Não use o campo destinado a perguntas para colocar comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro está aqui:

```
[StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Informe no máximo 80 caracteres")]
```

você está definindo o tamanho da string, forçando o sistema a completar a quantidade que falta, procure definir um maxlength no objeto e não na string.